# Web.Config <appsettings> section breaks site

Tags: asp.net

ASP.Net Data Retrieval site now erroring due to MS Patch limiting keys.
Trying to put the following section into web.config to up the number of keys

```
<appsettings>
   <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000"></add>
</appsettings>
```

Adding the section causes an Internal Server Error 'The configuration section 'appsettings' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration'

Any idea how to correctly add this section? I have tried variations of examples on the Web but I can't get past this.

Comment: Double check if you all ready have again the `appsettings` - and the correct is `appSettings` (the "S" capital).

Comment: Also makesure that `<appSettings>` is inside of `<configuration>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Watch the case of the tags--I'm pretty sure web.configs are case-sensitive.  Here is a full web.config, with appSettings nested inside of configuration...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>   
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank You all. I blindly copied the 'fix' from the net. Much appreciated.